# Getting "[NSRunLoop addPort:forMode:]: port argument cannot be nil'" when doing "carthage update" for Xcode 11

Tags: ios, carthage, swift5, xcode11

I'm updating my existing project code for iOS 13 using Xcode 11. I have some outdated Carthages so I was updating them using

```
carthage update --platform ios
```

but I'm getting the error below every time. I also used

```
carthage update Alamofire --platform ios
```

Cartfile

```
github "Alamofire/AlamofireImage"
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" == 4.7.3
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift"
github "mac-cain13/R.swift.Library" == 4.0
github "radex/SwiftyUserDefaults" == 3.0
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" == 3.4.0
github "chatous/ios-utilities" ~> 0.0.5
github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" == 10.0.0
github "rechsteiner/Parchment" == 1.1
github "Vadim-Yelagin/DataSource" == 0.5.4
github "rs/SDWebImage" == 4.4.2
github "Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField" ~> 3.6.0
github "jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField" ~> 1.2.1
github "danielgindi/Charts" == 3.1.1
github "fjcaetano/ReCaptcha" == 1.4.1
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
```

My Carthage version is 0.33.0.
My MacOS version is 10.14.5.

```
Vishal-Virodhia-MBP: ios-copy castle$ carthage update --platform ios
*** Fetching ObjectMapper
*** Fetching SkyFloatingLabelTextField
*** Fetching R.swift.Library
*** Downloading binary-only framework FirebaseAnalyticsBinary at "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
*** Fetching DataSource
*** Fetching SwiftyUserDefaults
*** Fetching Parchment
*** Fetching ReactiveSwift
*** Fetching Charts
*** Fetching SDWebImage
*** Fetching AlamofireImage
*** Fetching ios-utilities
*** Fetching ReCaptcha
*** Fetching ReactiveCocoa
*** Fetching JVFloatLabeledTextField
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Downloading binary-only framework FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary at "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary.json"
*** Fetching RxSwift
*** Fetching Result
2019-07-08 16:12:42.707 carthage[13767:10252146] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRunLoop addPort:forMode:]: port argument cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0cfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6fe90a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0b2f +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d150d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) addPort:forMode:] + 127
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d42f0 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 4060
    5   carthage                            0x000000010a6c5369 $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_ + 1049
    6   carthage                            0x000000010a6c86fa $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_TA + 42
    7   carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    8   carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    9   carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    10  carthage                            0x000000010a66a316 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtF17startNextIfNeededL_yyAaDRzAFRs_r0_lF + 838
    11  carthage                            0x000000010a66ab60 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_ + 640
    12  carthage                            0x000000010a670f2d $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TATm + 29
    13  carthage                            0x000000010a670570 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TA + 16
    14  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    15  carthage                            0x000000010a686e98 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 872
    16  carthage                            0x000000010a69e039 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GFTA + 9
    17  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    18  carthage                            0x000000010a6b6fd3 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEFAJyq0_q1__GAaF_pXEfU_yAH5EventOyxq__GcfU_TA + 51
    19  carthage                            0x000000010a657fb9 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO3mapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtcqd__xclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_ + 425
    20  carthage                            0x000000010a662f2d $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO10attemptMapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtc6ResultAKOyqd__q_GxclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_TATm + 45
    21  carthage                            0x000000010a662ce0 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO3mapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtcqd__xclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_TA + 16
    22  carthage                            0x000000010a67375a $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4send5valueyx_tF + 138
    23  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba63d $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV5valueACyxq_Gx_tcfcyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA10Disposable_ptcfU_TA + 29
    24  carthage                            0x000000010a6a8063 $S13ReactiveSwift13GeneratorCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 195
    25  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7996 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 182
    26  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7f06 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lF + 134
    27  carthage                            0x000000010a6b7035 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lFTA + 21
    28  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    29  carthage                            0x000000010a670476 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVA2A0cD11ConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE10concurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLL5limitACy5ValueQzq_GSu_tFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyAKq__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 214
    30  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    31  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    32  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    33  carthage                            0x000000010a6c4cdf $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 2463
    34  carthage                            0x000000010a6c7161 $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 17
    35  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    36  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    37  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    38  carthage                            0x000000010a6a8eb0 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV4liftyACyqd__qd_0_GAA0C0Cyqd__qd_0_GAGyxq_Gcs5ErrorRd_0_r0_lFyAG8ObserverCyqd__qd_0__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 208
    39  carthage                            0x000000010a6b43b1 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV4liftyACyqd__qd_0_GAA0C0Cyqd__qd_0_GAGyxq_Gcs5ErrorRd_0_r0_lFyAG8ObserverCyqd__qd_0__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 33
    40  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    41  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    42  carthage                            0x000000010a6a77f0 $S13ReactiveSwift10SignalCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 192
    43  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7996 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 182
    44  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7f06 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lF + 134
    45  carthage                            0x000000010a6b7035 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lFTA + 21
    46  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    47  carthage                            0x000000010a6b1386 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV5_thenyACy5ValueQyd__q_Gqd__5ErrorQyd__Rs_AA0cD11ConvertibleRd__lFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyAFq__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 198
    48  carthage                            0x000000010a6b7be5 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV5_thenyACy5ValueQyd__q_Gqd__5ErrorQyd__Rs_AA0cD11ConvertibleRd__lFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyAFq__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 37
    49  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    50  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    51  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    52  carthage                            0x000000010a66f9e1 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV12flatMapErroryACyxqd__GAEq_cs0G0Rd__lFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxqd___G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 577
    53  carthage                            0x000000010a66ffb5 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV12flatMapErroryACyxqd__GAEq_cs0G0Rd__lFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxqd___G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 37
    54  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    55  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
                            0x000000010a67381e $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC13sendCompletedyyF + 14
    306 carthage                            0x000000010a67b1c3 $S13ReactiveSwift15MutablePropertyCfD + 19
    307 carthage                            0x000000010ad65ca0 _swift_release_dealloc + 16
    308 carthage                            0x000000010a673fc4 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC5value6failed9completed11interruptedAEyxq__GyxcSg_yq_cSgyycSgAMtcfcyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_ + 500
    309 carthage                            0x000000010ad65ca0 _swift_release_dealloc + 16
    310 carthage                            0x000000010a674295 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverCfd + 165
    311 carthage                            0x000000010a6742b9 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverCfD + 9
    312 carthage                            0x000000010ad65ca0 _swift_release_dealloc + 16
    313 carthage                            0x000000010ad596ab swift_arrayDestroy + 59
    314 carthage                            0x000000010aa62306 $Ss23_ContiguousArrayStorageCfD + 54
    315 carthage                            0x000000010ad65ca0 _swift_release_dealloc + 16
    316 carthage                            0x000000010a688bd9 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC22tryToCommitTerminationyyF + 937
    317 carthage                            0x000000010a686e00 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 720
    318 carthage                            0x000000010a69e039 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GFTA + 9
    319 carthage                            0x000000010a6739d6 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC13sendCompletedyyFTm + 118
    320 carthage                            0x000000010a67381e $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC13sendCompletedyyF + 14
    321 carthage                            0x000000010a6c8f14 $S12ReactiveTask4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC23transferReadsToProducer0A5Swift06SignalN0Vy10Foundation4DataVAA0B5ErrorOGyFyAF0P0C8ObserverCyAkM_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_ys5Int32VcfU_TA + 36
    322 carthage                            0x000000010a930437 $Ss5Int32VIegy_ABIeyBy_TR + 39
    323 libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff716105f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    324 libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7161163d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    325 libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff716178e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    326 libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71618396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    327 libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff716206ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    328 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71851611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    329 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff718513fd start_wqthread + 13
)
2019-07-08 16:12:42.770 carthage[13767:10252145] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRunLoop addPort:forMode:]: port argument cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0cfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6fe90a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0b2f +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d150d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) addPort:forMode:] + 127
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d42f0 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 4060
    5   carthage                            0x000000010a6c5369 $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_ + 1049
    6   carthage                            0x000000010a6c86fa $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_TA + 42
    7   carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    8   carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    9   carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    10  carthage                            0x000000010a66a316 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtF17startNextIfNeededL_yyAaDRzAFRs_r0_lF + 838
    11  carthage                            0x000000010a66ab60 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_ + 640
    12  carthage                            0x000000010a670f2d $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TATm + 29
    13  carthage                            0x000000010a670570 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TA + 16
    14  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    15  carthage                            0x000000010a686e98 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 872
    16  carthage                            0x000000010a69e039 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GFTA + 9
    17  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    24  carthage                            0x000000010a6a8063 $S13ReactiveSwift13GeneratorCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 195
    25  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7996 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 182
    26  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7f06 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lF + 134
    \                  0x00007fff7161fb46 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 90
    124 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff718516b3 _pthread_wqthread + 583
    125 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff718513fd start_wqthread + 13
)
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2019-07-08 16:12:42.771 carthage[13767:10314704] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRunLoop addPort:forMode:]: port argument cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0cfd __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6fe90a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff457e0b2f +[NSException raise:format:] + 201
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d150d -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) addPort:forMode:] + 127
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff479d42f0 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 4060
    5   carthage                            0x000000010a6c5369 $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_ + 1049
    6   carthage                            0x000000010a6c86fa $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_AqA4Pipe33_8622FA0C3FE9071537A42FE3BB905E34LLC_A4_tcfU0_yA__A1_tcfU_TA + 42
    7   carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    8   carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    9   carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    10  carthage                            0x000000010a66a316 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtF17startNextIfNeededL_yyAaDRzAFRs_r0_lF + 838
    11  carthage                            0x000000010a66ab60 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_ + 640
    12  carthage                            0x000000010a670f2d $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TATm + 29
    13  carthage                            0x000000010a670570 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalCA2A0C19ProducerConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE17observeConcurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLLyAA10Disposable_pSgAC8ObserverCy5ValueQzq__G_SuAA8LifetimeCtFyAC5EventOyxq__GcfU_TA + 16
    14  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    15  carthage                            0x000000010a686e98 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 872
    16  carthage                            0x000000010a69e039 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC4Core33_6DF632AE8A9288C3EAD8EFDF3D3AF99ELLC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GFTA + 9
    17  carthage                            0x000000010a6737b7 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4sendyyAC5EventOyxq__GF + 39
    18  carthage                            0x000000010a6b6fd3 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEFAJyq0_q1__GAaF_pXEfU_yAH5EventOyxq__GcfU_TA + 51
    19  carthage                            0x000000010a657fb9 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO3mapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtcqd__xclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_ + 425
    20  carthage                            0x000000010a662f2d $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO10attemptMapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtc6ResultAKOyqd__q_GxclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_TATm + 45
    21  carthage                            0x000000010a662ce0 $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC5EventO3mapyyAEyxq__GcyAEyqd__q__Gc_AA8LifetimeCtcqd__xclFZyAGcyAHc_AJtcfU_yAGcfU_TA + 16
    22  carthage                            0x000000010a67375a $S13ReactiveSwift6SignalC8ObserverC4send5valueyx_tF + 138
    23  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba63d $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV5valueACyxq_Gx_tcfcyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA10Disposable_ptcfU_TA + 29
    24  carthage                            0x000000010a6a8063 $S13ReactiveSwift13GeneratorCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 195
    25  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7996 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC5startyAA10Disposable_pAA6SignalC8ObserverCyxq__GAaF_pXEF + 182
    26  carthage                            0x000000010a6a7f06 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lF + 134
    27  carthage                            0x000000010a6b7035 $S13ReactiveSwift15TransformerCore33_8C2AEE826CBF26B7535B1491D314A4F4LLC12makeInstanceAA014SignalProducerD0C0N0Vyxq__GyF16observerDidSetupL_yys5ErrorR_sALR1_r2_lFTA + 21
    28  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    29  carthage                            0x000000010a670476 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVA2A0cD11ConvertibleRz5ErrorQzRs_rlE10concurrent33_6345D8752C3E65AA1118F4C784F9873DLL5limitACy5ValueQzq_GSu_tFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyAKq__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 214
    30  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    31  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    32  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    33  carthage                            0x000000010a6c4cdf $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 2463
    34  carthage                            0x000000010a6c7161 $S12ReactiveTask0B0V6launch13standardInput0A5Swift14SignalProducerVyAA0B5EventOy10Foundation4DataVGAA0B5ErrorOGAHyAM6Result02NoL0OGSg_tFyAF0G0C8ObserverCyAnP_G_AF8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 17
    35  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    36  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    37  carthage                            0x000000010a6a3207 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV09startWithC0yqd__qd__AA0C0Cyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXElF + 247
    38  carthage                            0x000000010a6a8eb0 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV4liftyACyqd__qd_0_GAA0C0Cyqd__qd_0_GAGyxq_Gcs5ErrorRd_0_r0_lFyAG8ObserverCyqd__qd_0__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_ + 208
    39  carthage                            0x000000010a6b43b1 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV4liftyACyqd__qd_0_GAA0C0Cyqd__qd_0_GAGyxq_Gcs5ErrorRd_0_r0_lFyAG8ObserverCyqd__qd_0__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_TA + 33
    40  carthage                            0x000000010a6ba556 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_10Foundation4DataV_So13NSURLResponseCt_6Result8AnyErrorVTg5TA + 86
    41  carthage                            0x000000010a6baa29 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerVyACyxq_GyAA0C0C8ObserverCyxq__G_AA8LifetimeCtccfcAA0cD4CoreC8InstanceVyxq__GycfU_yycfU_TA + 9
    ...
    44  carthage                            0x000000010a6b16a2 $S13ReactiveSwift14SignalProducerV5_thenyACy5ValueQyd__q_Gqd__5ErrorQyd__Rs_AA0cD11ConvertibleRd__lFyAA0C0C8ObserverCyAFq__G_AA8LifetimeCtcfU_yALyxq_G_AA10Disposable_ptXEfU_yAL5EventOyxq__GcfU_ + 306
    45  carthage                            0x000000010a6b7c99 $S13ReactiAbort trap: 6
```

Comment: @GinoMempin Here is the cart file https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf6stm16chi5cm0/cartfile?dl=0

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the Cartfile? All info related to the Question must be included _with_ the post, not as an external link. Not everyone has access to Dropbox, and that link could change or disappear in the future, rendering this post useless for future readers.